# How to display CMIS document in web browser

Tags: cmis

I get document from CMIS. I get document content stream (ContentStream), but I can't figure out how to display this content in browser. Only I know how to save as a file.

Comment: are you doing this in a web-server as a response?  Or is this a client executable and you want to bring up a browser?  What language?

Comment: Java. I have servlet and I want to display document in a browser,  in main part of webpage. Rest of page should be the same for all documents.

Document doc = (Document) cmisSession.getObject(documentId);

Now I have contentStream, but I don't know how display it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a URL that will display the content nicely on the browser, that can only happen with a limited set of MIME types, namely with the ones your browser supports rendering for.

For example, currently in `cmis.alfresco.com` there's a node with ID `workspace:SpacesStore/i/6873cce7-73b1-4209-8d79-b16b694f02d3`, for which the `getObject` document lists the following:

```
<content type="text/plain" src="http://cmis.alfresco.com:80/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/6873cce7-73b1-4209-8d79-b16b694f02d3/content"/>
```

As it's set to be `text/plain` my browser (Chrome) displays it nicely on screen.